# How determine encoding of datetime.strftime(...) in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, encoding, unicode

I want to create a "unicode sandwich" that includes some date/time values and is locale independent. For the uninitiated, the term unicode sandwich describes the practice of converting from bytes to unicode and back at the boundaries of your program, i.e. bytes on the outside and unicode on the inside.

I watched [Ned Batchelder's excellent video on unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) this morning and am attempting to convert some of my code to be consistent with his wise advice.

The problem I'm having is I can't work out how to determine the encoding of a string returned by `str(date)` or its equivalents. What I have in mind is to do something like this, a little verbose for clarity:

```
date_str_encoding = some_magical_method_I_have_yet_to_discover()
date = datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 16).date()
date_str = date.strftime('%A %B %d, &Y')  # perhaps 'Sábado Octubre 19, 2013'
date_unicode = date_str.decode(date_str_encoding)
```

One of Ned's unicode "facts of life" is "You cannot infer the encoding of bytes. You must be told or you have to guess." Unfortunately, I can't find that particular detail in the Python docs for datetime.

Another SO post mentioned the use of locale.getlocale(), but that returns (None, None) for me.

How can I reliably discover the encoding of a Python date string at run time?

Comment: Python 2.x str is `ASCII`. What's your question exactly?

Comment: Python 2.x str is a sequence of bytes. It does not have an attribute which defines the *encoding* of those bytes. As Ned mentions in his talk, you have to know, be told, or else are reduced to guessing.

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding() gives system default encoding. Does it help?

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding() is not the right place to look I don't believe. The Python docs say to use locale.getlocale()[1] to get the current locale's encoding, which sounds like the right thing to do. The problem is I get `None` returned for that value. `locale.getdefaultlocale()` returns a plausible value, but won't be correct necessarily if someone has set the locale to something else. Could it be I have to check getlocale() and fall back to getdefaultlocale() if the former returns None? I can't believe the Python library guys would have done it that way, did they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in CPython 2.7, `datetime.date.strftime` is a wrapper around `time.strftime`, which in turn is a wrapper around the posix [`strftime(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).  In principle this is dependent the locale category of `LC_TIME`.  As such, what you are looking for is:

```
import locale
def date_format_encoding():
    return locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)[1] or locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

Below is a deconstruction of `datetime.date.__str__`, relevant before the edit of the question.

in CPython 2.7, `datetime.date.__str__` is implemented in C, it is:

```
static PyObject *
date_str(PyDateTime_Date *self)
{
    return PyObject_CallMethod((PyObject *)self, "isoformat", "()");
}
```

`datetime.date.isoformat` is in turn is implemented in C as:

```
static char *
isoformat_date(PyDateTime_Date *dt, char buffer[], int bufflen)
{
    int x;
    x = PyOS_snprintf(buffer, bufflen,
                      "%04d-%02d-%02d",
                      GET_YEAR(dt), GET_MONTH(dt), GET_DAY(dt));
    assert(bufflen >= x);
    return buffer + x;
}
```

Basically, there is never a case in which the bytes returned by `str(datetime.date)` are anything other than the ascii codes for digits and "-".  It is *always* correct to say:

```
str(my_date).decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Ah, very good to know! That takes care of part of my problem anyway :) Now I'm just left with the question of strftime() possibly returning a day word like 'Sábado'. Thanks @deque :)

Comment: @scanny: I see you edited your question, so I edited my answer, Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Why not skip `date_str` entirely? The `unicode` constructor accepts date objects.

```
>>> date_unicode = unicode(date)
>>> date_unicode
u'2013-10-16'
```

Internally, this calls `str(date)`. It then decodes those bytes. So it's equivalent to explicitly creating the bytes and then decoding them, but in my opinion clearer to read. And it's worth getting into the habit of using `unicode` rather than explicitly using `str` and `decode` because some objects will define a `__unicode__` method that can return a canonical Unicode representation without going through `__str__` at all. Dates do not.

The docs say:

> For a date d, str(d) is equivalent to d.isoformat().

Which is defined as:

> Return a string representing the date in ISO 8601 format, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’. For example, date(2002, 12, 4).isoformat() == '2002-12-04'.

So that will also be ASCII. If your default encoding can't decode ASCII you'd have already had to learn how to handle that situation.

Comment: The circumstances I was thinking of are like getting 'Sábado' back for the day word. I'll change my example to use the datetime.strftime() function instead of just str(). Btw, the unicode() function has an optional encoding parameter that defaults to 'ascii'. So the way you've used it above is equivalent to unicode(date, 'ascii') and would raise a UnicodeEncodeError if it encountered a non-ascii character. Admittedly that WOULD be bizarre for a simple date string, I'll change my example :)

Comment: Yeah, if you're using `strftime` rather than just the built in `str` representation you have to use `locale.getlocale` - if that returns `None` for the encoding, that means the encoding couldn't be determined. In practice, I expect that would mean `ascii`. The docs imply that the `unicode` constructor does not respect the `encoding` parameter when given something that it has to convert to a string first - "For all other objects, the 8-bit string version or representation is requested and then converted to a Unicode string using the codec for the default encoding in 'strict' mode.".

Comment: Hmm, good point @Peter. I'm disinclined to use the `unicode()` builtin anyway because I want a Python 2 + 3 solution. I haven't carefully thought through what that will take, but that's why I chose decode() instead of unicode(). I wonder what it means when Python "couldn't determine the locale". My current working theory is I'll have to test locale.getlocale() and if it's (None, None), fall back to locale.getdefaultlocale(). Seems like a lot of code for a seemingly simple query though :)

Comment: I'll be surprised if you get code that works unmodified in both 2 and 3 - `strftime` returns a Unicode object in 3. I'm not familiar enough with the POSIX locale library that the Python one is built on to be sure about it, but maybe this quote from the docs is relevant? "According to POSIX, a program which has not called setlocale(LC_ALL, '') runs using the portable 'C' locale." After making that call I get the expected results from `getlocale()` - though obviously you don't want that if your program is set to something other than the default locale.